# Написать запрос на подсчёт учеников

Tags: mysql

[image: База данных]
Написать запрос: который бы выводил количество учеников
каждого класса, с указанием наименования
класса и номера школы. У меня выводит суммарное кол-во учеников, причём заносятся они в первый класс:

`

```
SELECT 
    Class_Name AS 'Класс',
    School_Name AS 'Номер школы',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Кол-во учеников'
FROM school.schoolboy
  NATURAL JOIN school.school
  NATURAL JOIN school.class
GROUP BY 'idClass'
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Немного нужно дополнить список в GROUP BY

```
SELECT
   s.School_Name School
   c.Class_Name Class
   COUNT(*) Schoolboys
FROM school s
   LEFT JOIN Schoolboy sb ON s.idSchool = sb.idSchool
   LEFT JOIN Class c ON sb.idClass = c.idClass
GROUP BY s.idSchool, s.School_Name, c.idClass, c.Class_Name;
```